# Is it possible with GCC to put unintialized static/global variables into .data instead of .bss?

Tags: c, gcc

To preface, I am working to improve a romhacking tool used to automate injecting C code and data (targeting PowerPC) into a game executable.  The goal is to convert an ELF file into a binary blob (objcopy -O binary) in order to add as a new executable section.  However, in the process, all .bss information is lost.  Space is not a concern, so I would not mind if .bss were instead put into .data so it is not lost.  I cannot find any way to do this.

Comment: Try `-fno-zero-initialized-in-bss`.

Comment: -fno-zero-initialized-in-bss is only to disable the optimization where explicitly zero *initialized* variables are chucked into .bss.  I need .bss completely gone.

Comment: Hmm this is strange, gcc and clang do it differently. Perhaps you can use clang?

Comment: You can also try `-fdata-sections`. Another option is to postprocess the object files with `objcopy --rename-section`.

Comment: -fdata-sections only splits the .bss into a .bss for each uninitialized variable, according to the linker map.  --rename-section as well as --keep-section don't seem to work.
It seems like .bss isn't really treated like a proper section, so I thought a solution would be at the compilation step.

Comment: IIRC `.bss` is special compared to `.data`, because it is _not_ in the ELF file. Its entry just tells the address and size. -- Do you control the build of the ELF? Then you could provide your own linker script.

Comment: I ended up using https://github.com/eliben/pyelftools to copy the ELF sections' data into a binary file using Python.  This tool has the benefit of passing off a BSS section's data as a bytes object full of zeroes, which was exactly what I wanted.  Seeing as I was already using Python for the romhacking tool, this works great.